# Azure API Management log optimization and cost saving

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-log-analytics, ibm-api-management, cost-management

i have some instance of azure api management.
I didn't find on azure doc, so i have on api management setting:

[image]

both logging option enabled with all setting inside enabled. With actual configuration, both option enabled, i'm paying double for log?

Other question is, which kind of unuseful log i can disable on apim to save cost?

Regards

Comment: Hi @DeepDave-MT if i disable azure monitor what i lose? I lose the metrics or i lose the query inside log analytics?

Comment: Based on our understanding if we disable the azure monitor you will lose the metric and you will be able to run the queries in the log analytics workspace using the logs that were captured by application insights

Comment: If posted answer resolves your issue then you can accept and upvote the answer so that it will be helpful to other community members who might face the same issue.

Comment: Hi, we disabled azure monitor in dev and staging. We Will test It in the next weeks to see behavior. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save costs, you may use only App Insights for logging. However, please keep in mind that one does not replace the other fully, although there is some overlap.

- App Insights is a part of Azure Monitor, however, it acts as an automatic problem monitor as opposed to having a deep insight over your Azure infrastructure.
- If you do not require in your day-to-day activities a deeper insight of the APIs, such as telemetry analysis for example, then perhaps Azure Monitor is not needed.

There is also the option of setting for each [specific API and/or APIM instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtLFr.png), so if you run into performance issues on one you might want to use Azure Monitor, as opposed to only using App Insights.

Without deeper insight on the specifics of your business and infrastructure, my advice is to continue with both for the production instance, and cut back on Azure Monitor for dev and staging if you'd like.

Comment: Hi @VenkateshDodda i wrote in this topic without open another one. By the way i disabled azure monitor on apim under all apis to make cost saving. I didn't see any decrease of log under log analytics. Which kind of api log pass via api management under all api?